# Entity Framework Core: Read and Select Records using NOLOCK

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How do I read/select a in Entity Framework Core with NOLOCK? (to avoid locking/blocking/deadlocks in OLTP Database).
This is a sample select query.

```
var data= _dbContext.Set<ProductOrder>()
            .Where(c => c.ProductTypeId == this.productTypeId && c.saleYear == this.saleYear)
            .ToList();
```

Using Net Core 3.1 with SQL Server 2016 database.

Comment: That's the same as reading under the `READ UNCOMMITTED` transaction isolation level, so executing the whole thing under a transaction with that isolation level will have the same, terrible effect. Do not use `NOLOCK` if you can help it for anything where you actually need the result to be correct; there are [so many ways](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) it can go [very wrong](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/08/but-nolock-is-okay-when-the-data-isnt-changing-right/). Consider alternatives, like snapshot isolation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `NOLOCK` with `EF Core` like this

```cs
using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions
{
    IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
}))
{
    using (var db = new YourDbContext())
    {
        var data = db.Set<ProductOrder>()
            .Where(c => c.ProductTypeId == this.productTypeId 
                        && c.saleYear == this.saleYear)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

**Better solution:**

You can create an extension method that creates a `TransactionScopeOption` with `ReadUncommitted` state:

```
public static async Task<List<T>> ToListWithNoLockAsync<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> query, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default, 
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = null)
{
    List<T> result = default;
    using (var scope = CreateTrancation())
    {
        if (expression != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(expression);
        }

        result = await query.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

        scope.Complete();
    }
    return result;
}
private static TransactionScope CreateTrancation()
{
    return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                                new TransactionOptions()
                                {
                                    IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
                                },
                               TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);
}
```

Usage:

```
var categories = dbContext
    .Categories
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(a => a.IsDelete == false)
    .ToListWithNoLockAsync();
```

**Note:**

If you want to create a transaction with `ReadUnCommited` state for `async` methods, you should use `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled` in your `TransactionScope`.

---

This repository can be helpful for you [Github](https://github.com/farhadzm/EFCoreWithNoLock).

More information: [Implementing NOLOCK in EntityFramework](https://dotnetdocs.ir/Post/38/implementing-nolock-in-entityframework).

Comment: is it necessary to `new` a DbContext inside the TransactionScope? That won't work well in situations where a DbContext is injected to other things at construction time ...

Comment: Worked for me without the DbContext when I used: `new TransactionScope(scopeOption: TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions: new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }, asyncFlowOption: TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)`

Comment: HI, I'm trying this, but when I check the generated query by EF, it didn't have the "with(no lock)", should have it, right?

Comment: @Johna It's ok. But in `sql` profiler you should see `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`