Entity Framework Core - Performing NOLOCK queries with OData
I am trying to perform EF Core queries using NOLOCK, there is an article which demonstrated how to write an extension method, but it is not working as expected with OData query.
Here is the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63603655
query.ToListAsync is running the query against the table and trying to fetch millions of records. Whereas I am trying to pass this query with filters on
https://localhost:60484/odata/Users?$filter=userId eq 123&$expand=Products,Orders
So basically, I am trying to fetch records from user table where user id = 123 and also want to expand the products and orders foreign key properties as well.
// Controller method
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<IQueryable<User>> Get()
{
    return await _repository.UserRepository.GetUserData();
}

// Repository base
public async Task<List<T>> FindAll() => await _dbContext.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().ToListWithNoLockAsync();

// Repository method
public async Task<IQueryable<User>> GetUserData()
{
    var data = await FindAll();
    return data.AsQueryable()
                .Include(a => a.Products)
                .Include(a => a.Orders);
}

// Extension method from the article
public static class EFCoreTransaction
{
    public static async Task<List<T>> ToListWithNoLockAsync<T>(
                                        this IQueryable<T> query,
                                        Expression<Func<T, bool>>? expression = null,
                                        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        List<T>? result = default;

        using (var scope = CreateTransaction())
        {
            if (expression != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(expression);
            }

            result = await query.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

            scope.Complete();
        }

        return result!;
    }

    private static TransactionScope CreateTransaction()
    {
        return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                                    new TransactionOptions()
                                    {
                                        IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
                                    },
                                    TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);
    }
}


I'm sure you know that reading uncommitted data is a very bad idea? I really don't see why an OData endpoint should have this "feature". What's the underlying problem you're trying to solve? There must be better ways.

Well, I have tested the SQL query that is being generated in the logs and I have also traced the logs in our own trace tool, nowhere it is applying the nolock or read uncommitted. I know applying/appending nolock to a query from EF is  a very bad idea but I am not sure what's wrong with read uncommitted? The underlying problem is the get call is stuck if there are some other processes trying to update the same entity within a transaction scope then it get's locked and have to wait very long to retrieve the GET results. I haven't found a better way to apply read uncommitted.

We have very heavy SSIS processes/win services which are constantly trying to update the same entity that I am trying to GET from. You can test it yourself too, just create a GET endpoint and run a select query in db under a transaction scope and don't complete it, then come back and hit the GET EP, you will not get results and you'll be forced to wait on this until you rollback or complete the transaction from Database. Then apply the above solution and you'll get results smoothly. Let me know if I am wrong or any other ideas, I am open to discussions.

Just to make sure we're on the same page: nolock is more or less the same as read uncommitted. The problem is of course that you read data that may never get persisted. If you rely on the data for further processing things may go terribly wrong. The real problem is the long-running transaction, probably with serializable isolation (default for transaction scope) which locks everything it reads (on SQL Server). If anything should change, it's that process. Consider optimistic concurrency there.

I have found a way to do this. Eventually I can leave the repository classes untouched and just create the extension class as mentioned in the article.
Then, in the controller I made these changes by using ODataQueryOptions. As Iqueryable doesn't actually execute the DB query so it will fetch the records and then apply ToList() with read uncommitted. Any expert opinion is appreciated. I have tested this by checking the logs and SQL profiler. The generated query is being run under a transaction scope.
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(ODataQueryOptions<User> options)
{
    IQueryable<User>? tempQuery = _repository.UserRepository.GetUserData();
    if (options.Filter != null)
    {
        tempQuery = options.Filter.ApplyTo(tempQuery, new ODataQuerySettings()) as IQueryable<User>;
    }
    if (options.SelectExpand != null)
    {
        Request.ODataFeature().SelectExpandClause = options.SelectExpand.SelectExpandClause;
    }
    IQueryable<User> result = (await tempQuery!.ToListWithNoLockAsync()).AsQueryable();
    return Ok(result);
}

